# How to access custom variable from Material UI in NextJS with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, material-ui

I defined a custom variabel in MUI's theme, but Typescript is not recognizing it when I try to use it.

Here's the theme file:

```
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material";

declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
  export interface Theme {
    colors: any;
  }

  // allow configuration using `createTheme`
  export interface ThemeOptions {
    colors?: any;
  }
}

const theme = createTheme({
  colors: {
    grey: "#3e3e3e",
  },
});

export default theme;
```

And here is how I'm trying to use it:

```
const StyledClientDetails = styled("h3")`
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: ${(p) => p.theme.colors.grey};
`;
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Property 'colors' does not exist on type 'Theme'.ts(2339)
```

Here is my `_app.tsx` file just for good measure:

```
import * as React from "react";
import "@/styles/globals.css";
import Head from "next/head";
import { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
import { CacheProvider, EmotionCache } from "@emotion/react";
import theme from "@/styles/theme";
import createEmotionCache from "../createEmotionCache";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";

// If loading a variable font, you don't need to specify the font weight
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

// Client-side cache, shared for the whole session of the user in the browser.
const clientSideEmotionCache = createEmotionCache();

export interface MyAppProps extends AppProps {
  emotionCache?: EmotionCache;
}

export default function MyApp(props: MyAppProps) {
  const { Component, emotionCache = clientSideEmotionCache, pageProps } = props;
  return (
    <CacheProvider value={emotionCache}>
      <Head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width" />
      </Head>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
        <CssBaseline />
        <main className={inter.className}>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </main>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </CacheProvider>
  );
}
```